# Could not find libarcore

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement the AR project from Viro-Core but i get an error when i select the product. Instead of displaying the AR Model, It gives the following error:

> https://github.com/viromedia/virocore/blob/master/ARRetail/app/src/main/java/com/example/virosample/ProductARActivity.java
>
> 2019-03-26 14:39:35.028 27904-27904/com.example.virosample
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.virosample, PID: 27904
>       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.virosample-Nop8OFza79K-6aSOCygLyA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.virosample-Nop8OFza79K-6aSOCygLyA==/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.example.virosample-Nop8OFza79K-6aSOCygLyA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libarcore_sdk.so"
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
>           at com.google.ar.core.Session.(Session.java:97)
>           at com.viro.core.ViroViewARCore.requestARCoreInstall(ViroViewARCore.java:621)
>           at com.viro.core.ViroViewARCore.onActivityResumed(ViroViewARCore.java:820)
>           at com.example.virosample.ProductARActivity.onResume(ProductARActivity.java:140)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1412)
>           at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7557)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3979)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4019)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)

I expect an 3d model to show up, but the error mentioned about comes in the log